# Advanced CSS customization

Tags: html, css, jetty, zimbra

### The scenario

I have a quick CSS question. I am customizing the web interface of our Zimbra deployment, which uses jetty (something I haven't worked in before). I've identified two files that work together: (1) *skin.css*, and (2) *skin.properties*. The *skin.css* file includes the following line:

```
.ImgLoginBanner         {   background-repeat:no-repeat; @LoginBanner@   }
```

The `@LoginBanner@` appears to be a variable, and the other file (*skin.properties*) apparently holds the value. It has the following lines:

```
LoginBannerImg      =   @LogoImgDir@/LoginBanner.png?v=@jsVersion@
LoginBanner         =   @img(, LoginBannerImg, 400px, 158px)@
```

---

### What I am trying to do . . .

I want to customize it to insert my own `background-size` CSS property, but I can't seem to get it working correctly. In the *skin.css* file, I did this:

```
.ImgLoginBanner         {   background-repeat:no-repeat; @LoginBackgroundSize@; @LoginBanner@   }
```

And then in the *skin.properties* file I added the `LoginBackgroundSize` line:

```
LoginBannerImg      =   @LogoImgDir@/LoginBanner.png?v=@jsVersion@
LoginBanner         =   @img(, LoginBannerImg, 400px, 158px)@
LoginBackgroundSize = @background-size:400px 158px@
```

But it didn't work. I guess I am mis-understanding something here, but I am not sure what to google. I'm not familiar with this syntax. I don't even know what the values within the `@` symbols are called. "CSS variables" maybe?

---

### The question

- How are the *skin.css* and *skin.properties* files are working together?
- What is the `img()` function? Is that CSS?
- Why does the `LoginBannerImg` line in the *skin.properties* file
  have four `@` symbols? If it is to separate literal from symbolic text,
  then why does the `LoginBanner` line only have two?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured this out. The @ symbols aren't necessary in the *skin.properties* file. In the existing entries, they probably represent nested variables. I changed the LoginBackgroundSize from this:

```
LoginBackgroundSize = @background-size:400px 158px@
```

. . . to this:

```
LoginBackgroundSize = background-size:400px 158px
```

Worked immediately.